# Hide Activity Stream From Guests On Jomsocial

Tags: joomla

I am using Jomsocial and I managed to restrict access to profile details if you are a guest, but the activity stream is still visible.  How can I hide or disable the activity stream of a profile from a guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the administration panel, go to Layout and set the Show activity stream to members only
[image]